# Aplicar sum y count en distintas columnas de un dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

dispongo del siguiente dataframe de pandas:

```py
fecha = [Timestamp('2018-04-26 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-05-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-02-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-04-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-05-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-06-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-02-27 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-05-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-06-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-04-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-04-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-02-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-05-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-06-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-04-26 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-06-27 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-02-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-02-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-01 00:00:00')]
camion = [29, 142, 31, 45, 35, 37, 26, 27, 45, 39, 3, 32, 38, 37, 38, 44, 28, 33, 20, 19, 33, 45, 41, 40, 45, 142, 45, 41, 28, 31]
litros = [500, 1000, 1000, 750, 1000, 1000, 500, 854, 800, 1427, 1000, 300, 2939, 848, 95, 687, 500, 400, 1570, 759, 400, 500, 428, 208, 1800, 737, 1200, 473, 300, 600]
total = [395.0, 780.0, 740.0, 592.5, 765.0, 840.0, 355.0, 640.5, 604.0, 1013.17, 690.0, 253.5, 3497.410000000001, 924.32, 81.22, 494.64, 401.0, 310.0, 1114.7, 542.69, 280.0, 397.5, 350.96, 160.16, 1386.0, 523.27, 886.8, 354.75, 209.4, 454.8]
almacen = [1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 1]
ids = ['56Q0S4JD8138910', '5HV14A652495532', '54E1874LA464621', '56O11A401967278', '5720V2LHD857647', '5810IU5Z4491036', '55I0JPF62660479', '53V0MJMY1466389', '53N0U1I1L201206', '5550IOKNN936551', '5HV14A5AM346716', '57A0GUV8N180759', '57U0HE2YI612450', '53N0HTYJH885007', '55L0KJ7R7612606', '53Y0JCDZB003473', '56N0TQK4W986971', '56312BIV7788930', '5570JSBHX095290', '54L0YYF1Z018997', '55H0YC8ZH051478', '56Y0GPL8S406366', '58L0H8M82986461', '56Q11KSLA450419', '58H0GIP9A880489', '5HV14A4EQ001353', '55513RLEU103004', '54M0ICHQT431772', '53V0L7C95601821', '55610PU5K796614']

data = pd.DataFrame({'id': ids, 'fecha': fecha, 'litros': litros, 'total': total, 'almacen': almacen, 'camion': camion})
```

Quiero calcular cuantos días he empleado cada cantidad de camiones, es decir por ejemplo cuantos días he usado 2 camiones, cuantos 3, cuantos 9, esto agrupado por almacén y por año. Lo he conseguido hacer de la siguiente manera:

```py
datos = data
datos['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(datos['fecha'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
df = datos[['camion','litros','almacen','fecha','total','id']]
df['years'] = df.fecha.dt.year
agrup = df.groupby(['almacen','years','fecha'])[['camion']].nunique().reset_index()
dias_flota = agrup.groupby(['almacen','years','camion']).count().unstack().fillna('-')
```

De esta manera obtengo el siguiente DataFrame:
[image: dataframe resultado]

Ahora querría saber que cantidad de litros y que cantidad de pedidos tengo cada día con los los camiones mentados, es decir, los días que tengo en el almacén 1 en 2017 , 1 solo camión, cuantos litros he repartido esos días, y cuantos pedidos he despachado esos días para hacer posteriormente un promedio. Llego a calcular cada día cuantos litros tengo de la siguiente manera:

```py
litros = df.groupby(['almacen','years','fecha'])[['litros']].sum()
```

pero no llego a ver como combinar ambos datos ni como agruparlos de manera adecuada. 
Por la parte de la estadística tampoco tengo claro del todo que este valor aporte demasiado, si viesen alguna otra relación util con estos datos agradecería recomendaciones.
Si no fuesen suficientes los datos puedo ampliar el dataframe practicamente de manera indefinida. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según indicas, entiendo que quieres calcular columnas agregadas (count, mean, sum...), agrupando tus datos por `almacen` y `fecha`. Para conseguirlo tienes algunas opciones como estas (partiendo de tu dataframe `data`):

**Opcion 1:**

```
datos = data.groupby(['almacen','fecha'])['litros'].agg(['count','sum','mean'])
datos.head()
```

Con es primera opción tendrías calculados el número de camiones, la suma total de litros y la media de litros consumidos por almacen y día:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Opcion 2:**

Otra opción más elaborada y añadiendo algunas medidas adicionales que pueden resultar interesantes para el análisis, sería construyendo una función de agregación, donde puedes calcular las medidas que desees. En este caso, añadimos por ejemplo consumo de litros mínimo y máximo, rango de consumo. Esta es una adaptación de la respuesta ([44635626](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635626/rename-result-columns-from-pandas-aggregation-futurewarning-using-a-dict-with)):

```
def my_agg(x):
    names = {
        'Total_Camiones': x['camion'].count(),
        'Total_Litros':  x['litros'].sum(),
        'Consumo_Medio': x['litros'].mean(),
        'Rango_Consumo': x['litros'].max() - x['litros'].min(),
        'Consumo_Min':  x['litros'].min(),
        'Consumo_Max':  x['litros'].max()
}

    return pd.Series(names, index=['Total_Camiones','Total_Litros','Consumo_Medio', 'Rango_Consumo','Consumo_Min','Consumo_Max'])
```

Luego llamamos a la función usando el `groupby` que queremos (en este caso almacen/dia)

```
datos2 = data.groupby(['almacen','fecha']).apply(my_agg)
datos2
```

El resultado es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si el agregado se quiere por año, puede conseguirse usando la misma función de agregación `my_agg(x)` definida anteriormente:

```
data['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(data['fecha'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
data['year'] = data.fecha.dt.year

datos3 = data.groupby(['almacen','year']).apply(my_agg)
datos3
datos3.head()
```

Y tendremos un resultado como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Opción 3:**

Si quieres trasponer los resultados, para poner la fecha en columnas y las medidas calculadas en cada fila, utilizando nuevamente la función de agregación que habíamos definido anteriormente (`my_agg(x)`), puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
datos4=data.groupby(['almacen','year','fecha']).apply(my_agg)
datos4_transposed = datos4.transpose() # or df1.transpose()
datos4_transposed
```

En este caso tendremos el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDITO PARA AGREGAR OPCION 4:**

Sobre datos2 añadimos un `.reset_index()` y partiendo de ese dataframe, puedes hacer otra funcion nueva de agregacion para las nuevas columnas y luego llamas a la función con un `groupby` sobre la columna Total_Camiones:

```
def my_agg2(x):
    names = {
        'Total_Dias': x['fecha'].count(),
        'Total_Litros/Dias':  x['Total_Litros'].sum(),
        'Media_Litros/Dias': x['Total_Litros'].mean(),
        'Rango_Litros/Dia': x['Total_Litros'].max() - x['Total_Litros'].min(),
        'Min_Litros/Dia':  x['Total_Litros'].min(),
        'Max_Litros/Dia':  x['Total_Litros'].max()
}

datos5 = datos2.groupby(['almacen','Total_Camiones']).apply(my_agg2)
datos5.head()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la suma y demás de los litros entiendo como hacerla, y igual que hasta donde has llegado, lo que quiero calcular es ahora que dispones del total de camiones cada día, calcular el total de días que se han empleado cada cantidad de camiones y el total de litros que se han repartido con esa cantidad de camiones, por ejemplo si en el 2018 he tenido 2 camiones 5 días, contar esos 5 y el total de litros acumulado de esos 5 días. Lo siento si no puedo explicarlo mejor, de todas maneras agradezco tu respuesta.

Comment: Hola @dpm24, no estoy segura de haber entendido bien esta última parte. He editado la respuesta para añadir un nuevo groupby sobre datos2 a la columna Total_Camiones para que te muestre almacen, total camiones y contador de días con ese total de camiones. Espero que sea eso a lo que te refieres y que te sea útil.